# How to find what are all the softwares installed/Uninstalled today?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, installation, powershell-2.0

In our Virtual machines , we will look into what are the application installed/Uninstalled in the particular day

Is there any way to find it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Win32_Product class is very slow to query. Filter as much as you can.

$computername="SomeServer"

$apps=get-wmiobject win32_product -filter "installdate='20120206'" -computer $computername

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Hicks. Thanks for your great book. I hope your experience and knowledge would help many as you joined stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

The [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) interface should work for this. Use the command line: `wmic product`

Here's a [blog article](http://blogs.sepago.de/helge/2010/01/14/how-to-list-all-installed-applications-from-the-command-line/) that describes it in more detail and how to obtain the result as a .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can find information on uninstalled applications but you can get some information from the registry (with WMI you can get only MSI packages):

```
Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*\' | Select-Object DisplayName,InstallDate,Publisher
```

Answer (score 1):

To get list of application installed by msiexec in a specific day use this:

```
$strComputer = "."

$colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_Product" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername $strComputer

$colitems | ? { $_.installdate -eq "yyyymmdd" }| select name
```

this for all installed applications an Microsoft KBs (needs filtering by date):

```
$Keys = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
$Items = $keys |foreach-object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath}
$items | select displayname , "(default)" , installdate
```

For the unistalled applications you need to query the `application events logs` from source "`MsiInstaller`" or a 'string search' of "uninstall" in the description of the event.